# show that if every $T$-invariant subspace of $V$ has even dimension then $T$ has no real eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $V$ is a real finite-dimensional vector space. Prove $T$ does not have a real eigenvalue if and only if every $T$-invariant subspace of $V$ has even dimension.

Work so far: $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $U$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V.$ Then $\left.T\right|_U \in \mathcal{L}(U,U).$ If $\dim U$ were odd, then (by a theorem in my textbook) $\left.T\right|_U$ would have an eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{R},$ so there exists a nonzero $u \in U$ such that $\left.T\right|_U(u)= \lambda u.$ This would imply that $T(u) = \lambda u,$ which would show that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T.$ But we assumed $T$ to have no eigenvalues, so $\dim U$ must be even.

How do I prove the converse direction? I am stuck

Comment: If $Tv=\lambda v$ for some real $\lambda$, then $\operatorname{span}(v)$ is a one-dimensional $T$-invariant subspace?